# Validator in Laravel 5.6 not delivering $error messages

Tags: laravel-5.6

I am coding in Laravel 5.6 and i have a layout file called errors.blade with the contents of:

```
@if(session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>

@endif
@if(count($errors))
    <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        @foreach($errors as $error)
            <ul>
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            </ul>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

And my controller that insterts data into db and uses the $this->validate is:

```
public function store()
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed',
            'discord' => 'required'
        ]);
        Admin::create([
            'first_name' => request('first_name'),
            'last_name' => request('last_name'),
            'email' => request('email'),
            'username' => request('username'),
            'password' => bcrypt(request('password')),
            'discord' => request('discord'),
        ]);
        return redirect('/admin/login')->with('status', 'Install successfully completed. Use the form below to login to your account.');
    }
```

As you can see i am sending back a session with the name of status which i have setup to show in my errors file, which works perfectly. But as soon as i leave a field blank or mismatch the passwords on purpose i get this from the actual $errors:

[image]

This is happening on all pages. I don't know what exactly is the problem. The status messages work, but the error message here doesn't work. It happens with any error with validator or even with the:

> return redirect()->route('admin-login')***->withErrors('Incorrect
>   Username or Password.');***

Just a little more info, i am using a guard for admin and guard for the default laravel web to separate sessions of admin and regular users. I don't know if this could be any of the cause. Any help is greatly appreciated to remove this road block for me and any other users who have ran or may run into this.

Answer (score 1):

Change the @foreach to this:

> @foreach($errors->all() as $error)